# Module 'html5lib.filters.sanitizer' has no attribute 'allowed_elements'

Tags: django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I am not able to add any content in the page it is throwing the error

```
AttributeError at /en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/

module 'html5lib.filters.sanitizer' has no attribute 'allowed_elements'
```

Comment: What version of django & cms & html5lib? Can you add the full stacktrace? And what plugin is it? What version of that plugin?

Comment: There's a probably workaround here; https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/6401

Comment: Upgrading from html5lib==0.9999... to html5lib==1.0.1 solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your virtualenv and install html5lib in version 0.999999999

```
pip install html5lib==0.999999999
```

For me works fine :)